# Bluetooth Pairing on Dual boot of Windows & Ubuntu - Stop having to Pair Devices Repeatedly

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, mint

When switching from Windows to Ubuntu, you may find yourself having to pair your device again. This will happen every time you enter Ubuntu.

Now, how do you prevent this?

This answer also listed itself as a solution to Mint (a distro based on ubuntu). Nearly a year after posting, it was closed and downvoted.   Solution relocated per mod request:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521198/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p/34521199#34521199

Comment: this looks like I may have commented on the wrong question

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: Oh wait, @Fabby this applies to Mint and Ubuntu - the title even said so already.  I wanted to be inclusive to the mint community, but if I need to remove the reference to mint to unclose the conversation, I can do that.  Seems silly to close it just because it even mentions linux mint.

Comment: Then better delete here and post on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Alright. deleted.  

I'm not sure how that helps ubuntu users since this is a solution for ubuntu, but you have more rep points than me, so I have no choice I guess.

I had hoped to help myself and others, I'm not sure what is gained get out of skimming posts for the words "linux mint" and marking them as off topic.    This doesn't seem terribly welcoming.   Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was downvoted and closed a year after posting for being off topic since it referenced Linux Mint.

Per mod request, removed by original author. Reposted on main stackoverflow site.